# Force time series x labels on each year

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

Below I create a reproducible example chart ranging for 10000 days. As you can see this chart is highly informative and value adding, but it will do for the example.

Instead of one x label every 10 years, I would like to force a label every year. How can this be achieved?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
exdays <- 1:10000
exdata <- sin(exdays)
exdate <- as_date("2022-01-01")+days(exdays)
exdat <- tibble(exdate, exdata)
p1 <- ggplot(exdat, aes(x=exdate, y=exdata)) +
  geom_line(color="darkred", size=0.7) +
  ggtitle("example")
p1
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You maybe want this using `scale_x_date` with `date_breaks` of 1 year where you specify the `date_labels`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
exdays <- 1:10000
exdata <- sin(exdays)
exdate <- as_date("2022-01-01")+days(exdays)
exdat <- tibble(exdate, exdata)
p1 <- ggplot(exdat, aes(x=exdate, y=exdata)) +
  geom_line(color="darkred", size=0.7) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%Y") +
  ggtitle("example")
p1
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
p1 <- ggplot(exdat, aes(x=exdate, y=exdata)) +
  geom_line(color="darkred", size=0.7) +
  ggtitle("example") + scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year")
```